# How to rebase-file in Inkscape

Tags: command-line, inkscape

I am trying to get Inkscape to rebase (reload) an SVG file when my script generates a new version of the SVG. According to the 1.3 Release Notes there is a "New action 'rebase-file', which can replace the current document's contents by the contents of another file". According to Help>About my Inkscape is 1.3.2. However

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.exe" --actions=rebase-file
```

results in

```
InkscapeApplication::parse_actions: could not find action for: rebase-file
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also check this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/74040532/5920411

Comment: Side note: looking at the source code https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/actions/actions-file.cpp#L84-86 https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/document.cpp#L621 , looks like the way it works is to use the **current** file name, so it's not true that you can rebase on another file either.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in th release notes; the action is `file-rebase` not `rebase-file`.

To use the `file-rebase` action, you need to select the active window using the `-q` or `--active-window` flag:

```bash
inkscape --actions="file-rebase" -q 
# or
inkscape --actions="file-rebase" --active-window
```